# Identifying References in Python

Tags: python, memory, reference, web.py

I just spent a very long time debugging an issue in python, using the web.py framework, and it has me wondering about a way to check this kind of thing in the future.

In short, one of the methods of web.py's database class was returning a storage object that, I can only surmise, was a reference to a value in memory, instead of a copy. The result was that no matter what I tried to do, I could not append multiple results of a query into a list, because the list just wound up with copies of the same row of data.

To solve it, I had to create another dictionary and convert all values in the web.py storage object explicitly to another datatype (I just used strings to get it working) so that it would be forced to create a new object.

In code, this is what was happening:

```
>>> result = db.query(query_params)
>>> for row in result:
>>>     print row
...     result_list.append(row)
{"result" : "from", "row" : "one"}
{"result" : "from", "row" : "two"}
>>> print result_list
[{"result":"from", "row" : "two"}, {"result" : "from", "row" : "two}]
```

This is what clued me into the fact that this was some sort of reference issue. The list was storing the location of "row", instead of a copy of it.

The first thing I tried was something along the lines of:

```
 copy = {}
 for row in result:
    for value in row:
        copy[value] = row[value]
    result_list.append(copy)
```

But this lead to the same problem.
I only found a solution by tweaking the above to read:

```
            copy[value] = str(row[value])
```

So, my question is two-fold, really:

1. Is there an easy way to tell how something is being stored and/or passed around?
2. Is there a way to explicitly request a copy instead of a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html). It allows simple shallow- and deep-copying of objects in python:

```
import copy    
result_list.append(copy.copy(row))
```

Comment: I had no idea such a module existed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to how Python works. It's easy to identify which objects are passed by reference in Python: **all of them are.** It's just that many (integers, strings, tuples) are immutable, so you don't really notice when more than one name is pointing to them since you can't change them.

If you need a copy, make a copy explicitly. Usually this can be done using the type's constructor:

```
newlist = list(oldlist)
newdict = dict(olddict)
```

Lists can also do it with a slice, which you'll often see:

```
newlist = oldlist[:]
```

Dictionaries have a `copy()` method:

```
newdict = olddict.copy()
```

These are "shallow" copies: a new container is made, but the items inside are still the original references. This can bite you for, example, with lists of lists. A module called `copy` exists that contains functions for copying nearly any object, and a `deepcopy` function that will also copy the contained objects to any depth.

Comment: Thanks for the extra verbiage. I did not know that everything in python was passed by reference. That is, obviously, a very helpful thing!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about web.py, but most likely a `result_set.append(dict(row))` is what you were looking for.

See also: [`copy.copy()` and `copy.deepcopy()`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're curious about identity you can always check using the `is` operator:

```
>>> help('is')
```

The reason your attempt didn't work is because you were creating the dictionary outside the loop, so of course you're going to have problems:

```
>>> mydict = {}
>>> for x in xrange(3):
...     d = mydict
...     print d is mydict
...
...
True
True
True
```

No matter how many times you add things to `d` or `mydict`, `mydict` will always be the same object.

Others have commented that you should use copy, but they've failed to address your underlying issue - you don't seem to understand reference types.

In Python, everything is an object. There are two basic types - mutable and immutable. Immutable objects are things like strings, numbers, and tuples. You're not allowed to change these objects in memory:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> y = x
>>> x is y
True
```

Now `x` and `y` refer to the same object (not just have the same value).

```
>>> x += 4
```

Because 3 is an integer and immutable, this operation does not modify the value that's stored in `x`, what it actually does is adds 3 and 4 and finds out that it results in the value of 7, so now `x` "points" to 7.

```
>>> y
3
>>> x
7
>>> x is y
False
>>> y = x
>>> x is y
True
```

With mutable objects, you can modify them in place:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> mylist[0] = 3
>>> mylist
[3, 2, 3]
```

You'll have a lot easier time if you stop thinking about variables in Python as storing values in variables, and instead think of them as name tags - you know the ones that say "Hello, My Name Is"?

So essentially what's happening in your code is that the object being returned through your loop is the same one each time.

Here's an example:

```
>>> def spam_ref():
...     thing = []
...     count = 0
...     while count < 10:
...         count += 1
...         thing.append(count)
...         yield thing
...
>>> for a in spam_ref():
...  print a
...
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> spam = []
>>> for a in spam_ref():
...      spam.append(a)
...
```

So if you look at the output of the loop, you'd think that `spam` now contains

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

But it doesn't:

```
>>> for a in spam:
...  print a
...
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Because a list is mutable so the generator function was able to modify it in place. In your case, you have a dictionary that's being returned, so as others have mentioned, you'll need to use some method of copying the dictionary.

For further reading, check out [Python Objects](http://effbot.org/zone/python-objects.htm) and [Call By Object](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm) over at effbot.

Answer (score 0):

Either of two should work:

```
result = db.query(query_params).list()
result = list(db.query(query_params))
```

`db.query` and `db.select` return iterator, you need to convert it into list.